# ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am referring to the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.html#CONTENT_DIRECTORY. And I want to use the ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity URI for better results. APi level is 11 and my device OS is 4.0. I am using below code. And below is the exception I am getting in logs.
Please advice in which way I can use the ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity API.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/entities**

```
Cursor phones=null;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();     
Uri phoneuri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Uri phone_uri =  phoneuri.withAppendedPath(phoneuri,  ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
phones = cr.query(phone_uri, null, null, null, null);
for(int i=0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
{
    Log.e("int","f_name="+phones.getColumnName(i));
}
phones.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get all contacts from android:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
Cursor contacts = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                projection, null, null, "UPPER("
                                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
startManagingCursor(contacts);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
int contactId = 111;//one contact's id
Uri contactsUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactsUri, Contacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(entityUri,
         null,null, null, null);
```